# Navigation Controller interfering with TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a menu, which is just a tableview on a tab.  When you select one of the table cells it segues to a viewcontroller that is embedded in a navigation controller.  i have added a 'Done' button to this navigation controller and created a segue back to the menu.  however now the menu doesn't show the tabBar and it now shows a navigation bar with a 'Back" button on it.

This is the menu (part of tab bar) just a table view

[image]

This is the pages shown when clicking tableview cell

[image]

This is the menu again after clicking 'Done'

[image]

when clicking done i wanted it to go back to the menu as it was shown in the first screenshot.  i was trying to use the interface builder for this but guess i could create a class and go back to the menu via code.

Any ideas how to fix this?

----- EDIT -----

This is support page without 'Done' button

[image]

------ EDIT -----

this is the flow layout, sorry its messy working on small screen laptop atm

[image]

Comment: for displaying the SUPPORT PAGE, are you displaying it using pushviewcontroller or presentviewcontroller?

Comment: i am using push segue

Comment: if you don't setup the Done button, are you seeing the back button? Do you see a navigation bar?

Comment: i can see the navigation controller but there is no default back button, i added a screenshot to the bottom of the main question.

Comment: remove the bottom right navigation controller, it isn't needed as it is already in a navigation controller stack

Comment: Also, your navigation back from the support page is wrong. Your current method is pushing a new instance of the menu's navigation controller into your current navigation controller. You should link the done button via an IBAction and call `popViewController` or a better option would be to setup a unwindSeque method in your menu controller and link the Support Page's exit route to your unwindSegue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised you did not have a Navigation bar on your Menu Tab. All you need to do is embed in a navigation controller. Let me know if it does not work.

[image]

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
 indexPath: IndexPath){
    if(indexPath.row == THE_ROWNUMBER_OF_YOUR_SUPPORT_PAGE){
        let displaySupportPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SuppportPage") as! ChooseSalonTVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(displaySupportPage, animated: true)
    }

 }
```

[image]

Check "Hide Bottom Bar On Push"

Comment: It doesn't display the back button on the navigation bar, but i can't see the tab bar either when hitting the Done button

Comment: Please show your codes when calling Support Page, and codes for your Done button.

Comment: it has all been done in interface builder.  The tableview is static with segue from cell to navigation controller.  ill add screen shot of layout to original question

Comment: now i know why.... delete the uinavigationcontroller between your tableview and support page. Connect directly from YOUR TABLEVIEW (NOT TABLEVIEWCELL), to Support Page.

Comment: That fixed the problem, however now the tabBar is displayed on the support page.  is there a way to stop showing this?

Comment: add in the codes I've added. In your storyboard, on the view controller of the support page, under Identity Inspector, set your StoryboardID to "SupportPage". Also, based on the codes, you need to change the exact row number of THE_ROWNUMBER_OF_YOUR_SUPPORT_PAGE.

Comment: Select the View Controller that you want to hide the Tab Bar for and then select "Hide Bottom Bar on Push". It adds the tabBarHidden property (with isTabBarHidden as its getter) and the - (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated method

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "Show (e.g. Push)" segue and not "Push". This allows it to show itself correctly in the stack.

Using "Push" requires that the existing screen exists inside a navigation controller, which it doesn't on the first load. By using "Push" it is moving the controller into a navigation controller stack which leaves you with the navigation bar after pressing done.

By using the "Show (e.g. Push)" segue option, the system will chose to use a modal presentation or a navigation controller push based on your current view hierarchy.

Show (e.g. Push):

[image]

**Note:** if your view is shown using a Model presentation you need to use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and not

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can do a quick check to choose the correct method:

```
if (self.navigationController) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This will allow you to show the screen in multiple ways without having to do any additional checks

Comment: Ahhh, your wording made me think you was using the deprecated "Push" option :)

Comment: I got what you meant with your comment from your edit. I have adjusted my answer with your edit and some additional rewording

Comment: Note: if your view is shown using a Model presentation you need to use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and not `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`